# How to setLayoutParams on dynamically added elements on Widget

Tags: java, android, android-layout

currently, i'm adding elements dynamically to my widget using the following:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_design);

RemoteViews newView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);
views.addView(R.id.view_container, newView);
```

but how can I dynamically add margins, weights, and other properties to the added elements?

currently i have tried (using code I have found from different sites):

```
LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.widgetItem);
MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new MarginLayoutParams(item.getLayoutParams());
marginParams.setMargins(10, 50, 4, 5);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
item.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

but this force-closes

LogCat:

> 09-10 22:01:55.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30060): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-10 22:01:55.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30060):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver
>   com.example.test.HomeWidget: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext 09-10 22:01:55.283:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30060):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2821)
>   09-10 22:01:55.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30060):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125) 09-10
>   22:01:55.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30060):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
>   09-10 22:01:55.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30060):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 09-10
>   22:01:55.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30060):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 09-10 22:01:55.283:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30060):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 09-10
>   22:01:55.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30060):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-10
>   22:01:55.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30060):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 09-10 22:01:55.283:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30060):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>   09-10 22:01:55.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30060):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 09-10
>   22:01:55.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30060):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-10 22:01:55.283:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30060): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext 09-10 22:01:55.283:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30060):     at
>   com.example.test.HomeWidget.onUpdate(HomeWidget.java:37) 09-10
>   22:01:55.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30060):     at
>   android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider.onReceive(AppWidgetProvider.java:61)
>   09-10 22:01:55.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30060):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2810)
>   09-10 22:01:55.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30060):     ... 10 more

Comment: erm, ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30060): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext ?

Comment: It will be better if you copy here full stack trace, not just one line. After your app crashes copy the latest error (red lines) and add it to your question.

Comment: So what's on HomeWidget.java:37?

Comment: `code`LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.widgetItem);`code`

Comment: You're trying to cast some `context` to `Activity` which isn't really `Activity`.

Comment: well, a context is passed with the widget's `code`onUpdate `code`, but eclipse automatically added the cast of `code`Activity `code`, so i'm not sure of how to change it to work with the Widget..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LinearLayout layoutParams = item.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.setMargins(10, 50, 4, 5);
item.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Somehow creating new LayoutParams always causes such error. I think, there remain some fields unset. Only copy the existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

As I've already said in comments, you're trying to cast `context` to `Activity`. This context is not `Activity`. From `AppWidgetProvider.onReceive()`:

> `context` The `Context` in which the receiver is running.

Moreover you can't access an `Activity` from a widget.

If you want to call an `Activity` from a widget, you should register a `BroadcastReceiver` in this `Activity` and call it using `Context.sendBroadcast()`.

**EDIT**: And if you want to set `LayoutParams` for `RemoteViews`, you'd better do it in XML.

Comment: thanks for the response, but how would I set LayoutParams in XML when the values need to be dynamic?

Comment: Maybe there's some way but I don't know hot to do it. I think you shouldn't use dynamic margins in widgets.

Answer (score 0):

I have a method to change the bottom margin of any view for any amount of pixel.  You can go ahead and make it bit more generic for top, right and left margins as well.

```
private static void adjustViewHeight(int resID, int pixels, Activity activity){
    ((FrameLayout.LayoutParams)activity.findViewById(resID).getLayoutParams()).bottomMargin = pixels;
    activity.findViewById(resID).invalidate();
    activity.findViewById(resID).requestLayout();
}
```

Hope this helps,

-serkan